# Smallest group containing two given elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Given two elements of a finite group **a, b  Ԑ  G,** what is the smallest group containing both these elements?

Is it **{a<sup>x</sup>b<sup>y</sup>| x = 0, 1,...., m  &  y = 0, 1,...., n}** ? OR

Is it the Union, **{a<sup>x</sup>b<sup>y</sup>| x = 0, 1,...., m  &  y = 0, 1,...., n} U {b<sup>y</sup>a<sup>x</sup>| x = 0, 1,...., m  &  y = 0, 1,...., n}**?

where **m** and **n** are the orders of  **a** and **b** respectively..

What exactly do we mean when we talk of a subgroup generated by a given subset **S ⊂ G**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of these needs to be a subgroup. For example, if $a,b$ are generators of the free group $F_2$, then neither of these sets contain $aba$.

The smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $a$ and $b$ (called the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$) is
$$\langle a,b\rangle = \left\{a^{m_1}b^{n_1}\cdots a^{m_k}b^{n_k} : m_i,n_i\in \mathbb Z, k\in\mathbb N\right\}$$
Note that in general elements an element of $\langle a,b\rangle$ can be written in the form $a^{m_1}b^{n_1}\cdots a^{m_k}b^{n_k}$ in more than one way. The subgroup generated by a set $S\subseteq G$ is defined similarly, i.e.
$$\langle S\rangle=\left\{s_1^{n_1}\cdots s_k^{n_k} : s_i\in S, n_i\in \mathbb Z, k\in\mathbb N\right\}$$

Comment: What if we can deduce that the super group G is abelian?

Comment: @Ishfaaq In that case, both of the sets you wrote are identical and are the subgroup generated by $a,b$.