# Find the smallest subgroups of all permutations of $8$ elements which contain specific permutations

Tags: group-theory, permutations

The questions asks the following:

Find the smallest subgroups of $S_8$ (group of all permutations of $8$
elements) which contain respectively the permutation $f$ and the permutation $g$.

Where $f = (4 5 6 2 8 3 7 1)$ and $g = (8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)$.

I'm a complete loss to answer this question, I tried revisiting my course notes but I simply can't understand what this question even requires.

I *think* that the solution has to be $2$ groups, both starting with $\{(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)\}$ and permuting two elements until reaching $f$ and $g$ respectively. If so, how do I ensure the group is the smallest possible without brute forcing the solution?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm truly lost in this course.

Comment: **Hint:** $f$ and $g$ are $8$-cycles.

Comment: Are you saying your assignment has two parts? i.e. one to find the group corresponding to $f$, and the second to find the group corresponding to $g$?

Comment: @311411 That's the textual wording of the question, re-reading it I think it would be safe to assume that the answer would consist of two different subgroups, one containing *f* and one containing *g*. I'll update the question to make the distinction

Comment: You are dealing with the idea of "a (sub)group generated by a given set of elements". If you wanted the subgroup generated by $\{f,g\}$, that would be something like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602218

Comment: @311411 so the generator would be *f* and *g* respectively and the solution would be all the degrees of the permutation until a cycle is reached? Thanks in advance for your comments, they are a shining light at the end of the tunnel.

Comment: it has been a while since I looked at groups, but i think that is right. A subgroup generated by a single guy is just the powers of it, and is a cyclic group